# Detect if final character of innerHTML of an element is "1", if so, underline and make the last character green, and add some text to the front

Tags: javascript

So if the final character of the `innerHTML` of an element with id `output` is "1", I want to add:

```
<a style='color: Green; font-size: 32px;'>Our final result is 1!</a><br><br>`
```

to the front of the `innerHTML` of `output`, and make the last character ("1") be green and underlined. This is what I have tried so far:

```
var out = document.getElementById("output");
if(out.innerHTML.slice(-1) == "1") {
    out.innerHTML = "<a style='color: Green; font-size: 32px;'>Our final result is 1!</a><br><br>" + out.innerHTML;
    out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML.slice(0, -1) + "<u style='color: Green;'>" + out.innerHTML.slice(-1) + "</u>";
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<b id="output">
2 / 2 = 1
</b>
```

I also tried this:

```
var out = document.getElementById("output");
if(out.innerHTML.charAt(out.innerHTML.length - 2) == "1") {
    out.innerHTML = "<a style='color: Green; font-size: 32px;'>Our final result is 1!</a><br><br>" + out.innerHTML;
    out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML.slice(0,-2) + "<u style='color: Green;'>1</u>";
}
```

But both ways do not seem to work (meaning that there is no difference).

How do I get it to work then?

Comment: Show the element with `output` id

Comment: Maybe I wrong, but the last character in `out.innerHTML` appears to be newline (or other whitespace).

Comment: Yes I checked last character is newline

Comment: Wait, not closed yet. See edit.

Comment: there is line ending character ';' in second expression `out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);`

Comment: Sry just a typo error here, but it wasn't in my actual code

Comment: It does seem to work, http://jsfiddle.net/4xYf9/. What is the problem?

Comment: might be some incorrect tag closing in your actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

innerHTML will include new line as last character. do this as the first thing.

```
out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML.trim();
```